# How to make the pageControl swipe effect? The scroll view slides continuously so far

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I would like to make the swipe effect with the scrollView, I found a project where nothing is specifically invoked in the code or in the storyboard. I repeated the code, but in my project, the scrollView just slides continuously, it does not swipe from one imageView to the other. Would you know how to do this?

Here is the code, the scroll respond to the touch, the pagecontrol is a simple iboutlet, but there is no swipe effect (the scroll stops where the touch ends, instead of going back or moving the entire imageview ) :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    var pageViews: [UIImageView?] = []
    var pageImages : [UIImage?] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pageImages = [UIImage(named:"photo1.png"),
        UIImage(named:"photo2.png"),
        UIImage(named:"photo3.png"),
        UIImage(named:"photo4.png")]

        let pageCount = pageImages.count
        pageControl.currentPage = 0
        pageControl.numberOfPages = pageCount

        for _ in 0..<pageCount {
            pageViews.append(nil)
        }

        let pagesScrollViewSize = scrollView.frame.size
        println("pagesScrollViewSize : \(pagesScrollViewSize)")
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagesScrollViewSize.width * CGFloat(pageCount), pagesScrollViewSize.height)
        loadVisiblePages()
    }

    //when scrolling
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView!){
        loadVisiblePages()
    }

    func loadVisiblePages(){
        let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width
        let page = Int(floor( (scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0 + pageWidth) / (pageWidth*2.0) ))
        println("page: \(page)")
        pageControl.currentPage = page
        let firstPage = page-1
        let lastPage = page+1
        //remove all the pages before firstPage
        for var index = 0; index < firstPage; ++index{
            purgePage(index)
        }
        //load pages in our range
        for var index = firstPage; index <= lastPage; ++index {
            loadPage(index)
        }
        //remove after lastPage
        for var index = lastPage+1; index < pageImages.count; ++index {
            purgePage(index)
        }
    }

    func loadPage(index:Int){
        if index < 0 || index >= pageImages.count {
            return
        }
        if let pageView = pageViews[index] {
            //already loaded
        }
        else {
            var frame = scrollView.bounds
            frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
            frame.origin.y = 0.0
            println("\(frame)")

            var newImageView = UIImageView(image:pageImages[index])
            newImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            newImageView.frame = frame
            scrollView.addSubview(newImageView)

            pageViews[index] = newImageView
        }
    }

    func purgePage(index:Int){
        if index < 0 || index >= pageImages.count {
            return
        }
        if let pageView = pageViews[index] {
            pageView.removeFromSuperview()
            pageViews[index] = nil
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIPageControl` doesn't do the page-scrolling behavior — it provides only the dots that indicate which page is shown (and that a user can tap to jump between pages). Use the [`pagingEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/pagingEnabled) property of `UIScrollView` to scroll by page instead of continuously.

Or just use [`UIPageViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPageViewController) to get just about all the scrolling and paging business handled for you.